# How to keep width format in printf when saving to a variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following code

```
printf "%8s.%s\n" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM"
```

That produces the expected output

```
   24756.22971
    9910.13045
    7701.30924
   22972.27622
```

I would like to save this output with leading spaces in a variable for later uses like this

```
printf -v output "%8s.%s\n" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM"
```

However, if i try to print/echo the variable $output, leading spaces are gone:

```
24756.22971
9910.13045
7701.30924
22972.27622
```

Comment: note that what you're getting is a number of the form _x.y_, where both _x_ and _y_ are within the range 0..32767. Which in particular means that the fractional part can never more than about 1/3. If you want something where the fractional part is somewhat evenly distributed, you could use `RANDOM` divided by 32768, e.g. `printf "%d.%d\n" $RANDOM $(( RANDOM * 1000 / 32768 ))`, or in a shell like Zsh that supports floating point arithmetic: `printf "%.3f\n" $(( RANDOM + RANDOM / 32768.0 ))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using the variable `output` unquoted, as in

```bsh
printf '%s\n' $output
```

That would make the shell split the string in the variable on whitespaces (spaces, tabs, and newlines by default), i.e. it would delete the leading indentation.  You'd still get four lines of output from this, only because the format string of `printf` is reused for each word.

With `echo $output`, you'd get your data on a single line since that is what `echo` does, it outputs each argument (the split-up words from your string) with spaces between them.

Instead make sure that you are double quoting the expansion of `$output`:

```
printf '%s' "$output"
```

(I'm not putting a `\n` in the format string here since that would output an empty line at the end of your string, as it already ends with a newline).

See also:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)